# summing the values row wise

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, glob

I have a three column of data as arranged below:

Input file:

```
>>>>>
1.0 2.0 3.0
2.0 2.0 4.0
3.0 4.5 8.0
>>>>>
1.0 2.5 6.8
2.0 3.5 6.8
3.0 1.2 1.9
>>>>>
1.0 1.2 1.3
2.0 2.7 1.8
3.0 4.5 8.5
```

In the above input file the first column values are repeated so I want to take only once that value and want to sum the third column values row wise and do not want to take any second column values.

I also want to append a third column with the fixed value 1.0

Finally want to save the result on another test file called output.txt.

Output:

```
1.0  11.1  1.0
2.0  12.6  1.0
3.0  18.4  1.0
```

In the output second column values resulted from is following:

```
3.0+6.8+1.3
4.0+6.8+1.8
8.0+1.9+8.5
```

I tried with numpy but getting error:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob
data=np.loadtxt("input.txt")
```

Comment: this looks like  a groupby : ``df.groupby(0)[2].sum()``

Comment: Is it a single input data frame or all 3 are different?

Comment: this is single input data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read your input file using [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), you need to set the delimiter to `" "`, specify no header and `">"` as comment lines.

Then perform the `groupby`/`sum` operation, and export without header using [`pandas.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.to_csv.html)

```
import pandas as pd

# input
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', delimiter=' ', header=None, comment='>')

# output
(df.groupby(0)[[2]].sum()
   .assign(col=1.0)
   .to_csv('output.txt', header=False, sep=' ', float_format='%.2f')
)
```

output.txt:

```
1.00 11.10 1.00
2.00 12.60 1.00
3.00 18.40 1.00
```

Comment: output is nice, one more small querry, i just want to add extra column to the output.txt  by repeating a number and want to append it to the third column of output.

Comment: so output should be 1.00 11.10  1.0
2.00 12.60  1.0
3.00 18.40  1.0

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df[2].groupby(np.arange(len(df)) % 3).sum()
# or df.iloc[:, 2].groupby(np.arange(len(df)) % 3).sum()

0    11.1
1    12.6
2    18.4
Name: 2, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` with `reset index`

```
dfNew = df.groupby(0)[2].sum().reset_index()
dfNew.to_csv('output.txt', index= False)
```